# trouble with setup.py

Tags: python, python3

I'm running Disco Dingo 19.04, and attempting to install evillimiter to do some testing on my home network. However, I have run into a problem with python setuptools.

```
icarus@Omicron:~$ sudo bash
[sudo] password for icarus: 
root@Omicron:~# cd evillimiter
root@Omicron:~/evillimiter# sudo python3 setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Command
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
root@Omicron:~/evillimiter# sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-setuptools is already the newest version (40.8.0-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 390 not upgraded.
root@Omicron:~/evillimiter# sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-setuptools is already the newest version (40.8.0-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 390 not upgraded.
root@Omicron:~/evillimiter#
```

You can see, I already have setuptools installed, as well as -pip, python, and python3. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why are you running this command as root if this is your home computer network?

Comment: In the instructions it said to install it as root

Comment: install as root should mean run command with `sudo` and I see you use the `sudo` tool even when your already in the root account. Please provide a link to the instructions.

Comment: https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/control-network-traffic-with-evil-limiter-throttle-kick-off-devices-0196137/

Comment: I'm very new to linux..

Comment: Please exit from the root account and use the `sudo` command to install that application, exit with the command `exit`!

Comment: icarus@Omicron:~$ cd evillimiter
icarus@Omicron:~/evillimiter$ sudo python3 setup.py install
[sudo] password for icarus: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Command
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
icarus@Omicron:~/evillimiter$

Comment: You have a bigger problem: "*0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 390 not upgraded.*" Look up how to fix that first.

Comment: Please run these commands: `sudo apt install python-pip python-dev build-essential && sudo pip install --upgrade pip && sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv`, then try again.